# macOS detect if mouse button is down in KeyDown

Tags: swift, macos, keydown, mousedown, nsevent

In `keyDown(with event: NSEvent)` I can know if OPT, CMD, CTRL, Shift are pressed, with the following code

```
override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    let shiftPressed = (event.modifierFlags.rawValue & NSEventModifierFlags.shift.rawValue != 0)
    let commandPressed = (event.modifierFlags.rawValue & NSEventModifierFlags.command.rawValue != 0)
    let optionPressed = (event.modifierFlags.rawValue & NSEventModifierFlags.option.rawValue != 0)
    let controlPressed = (event.modifierFlags.rawValue & NSEventModifierFlags.control.rawValue != 0)
    ...
```

How can I detect if the left mouse button is up or down inside keyDown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you may notice, `keyDown:` tracks keyboard not mouse, so you need to track the mouse. Then :

Catch mouse events and track `mouseDown:`, set a flag inside it that you reset in `mouseUp:`, then test this flag in your `keyDown:`.

-----EDIT----

You may also poll the mouse (polling is not always a good idea anyway) with method `pressedMouseButtons:` of `NSEvent`.

Comment: I believe it _is_ the standard way. The same way you can not query the keyboard state when the mouse events occur, you can not poll the mouse state when the key events occur :-) It is up to you to setup variables to coordinate them.